# Error 500 After last then 1 minutes on Linux Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, amazon-rds

I am trying to run a long PHP process on my server. The process has about 10000 calls to external db server.

Server information:

- Linux ubuntu 14.04
- Apache/2.4.7
- DB Server - Amazon RDS Server  - MySql 5.6.27

When i try to run the process i get error 500 after 50-60 seconds.

I Changed the php.ini `memory_limit=1024M` And the `max_execution_time=180`. but unfortunately it did not help. also i am not getting any logs from Apache.

I Checked the logs from the db server but its look fine. also the max CPU on the time that the process was running was 16%.

I Have the same process run over another server with a local MySQL service and with the same php.ini Configuration and its work fine on this server.
I assume because it's requests to external serve it takes more time and memory so i am not sure that the problem is on the db side

what could be the problem? Something in the configuration of the php.ini? or in the AWS RDS?

Comment: Just to be complete and to make sure you edited the right config file: Have you tried `set_time_limit(180);`? Do you have Any specific error message?    Try `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to output error messages.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have one request going for that long like that. If possible, the request should just put a message on a queue of some kind that gets picked up by a separate worker process.

Comment: It looks like you have console access to the server, have you checked any error logs for an error description?

Comment: Thanks! @Thakkie It was  a problem with a query for some reason my display error was on 0

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with a query for some reason my display error was on 0 so i dident see the error